# AutoCompleteTextView в Android

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Использую `AutoCompleteTextView`, когда ввожу букву, то подтягивает только слова, которые начинаются с этой буквы, а как сделать что бы подтягивались все слова в которых есть эта буква? может есть какая-то другая разновидность `AutoCompleteTextView`?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] language ={"C","C++","Java",".net"," iphone","android","asp.net","php"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,language);
        AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        actv.setThreshold(1);
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);
        actv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }
}
```

Comment: нужно поменять код фильтрации результатов. Покажите ваш код.

Comment: @metalurgus добавила

Comment: Вам нужно переопределить у `ArrayAdapter` метод `getFilter()` таким образом, чтобы он возвращал необходимый фильтр. Как сделать - https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20autocompletetextview%20custom%20filter

Comment: Или тут https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20autocompletetextview%20contains

Comment: @metalurgus Ок, спасибо, буду смотреть!